# Is it true that $f(G_m × G_n) ⊂ G_{mn}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

For  $n ≥ 2$ we let $G_n ⊂ Z_n$ denote the
subset of all integers mod n which are invertible $\mod n$. Let $m, n \in 
\mathbb{Z}$ $m, n ≥ 2$ and $(m, n) = 1$. Deﬁne a mapping
$f : Z_m × Z_n → Z_{mn}$ as follows: set $f([a]_m, [b]_n) = [x]_n$ where $x$ is the
unique solution $\pmod {mn}$ given by the Chinese Remainder Theorem to the
simultaneous linear congruences
$$[x]_m = [a]_m$$
$$[x]_n = [b]_n.$$
I want to show $f(G_m × G_n) ⊂ G_{mn}$, and consequently that $f : G_m × G_n \to G_{mn}$ is bijective.

Can someone help me please? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is a unit modulo both $m$ and $n$ (i.e. invertible), then $\gcd(x,n) = \gcd(x,m) = 1$.  That also means $\gcd(x,mn) = 1$ or else there is a prime dividing either $m$ or $n$, and $x$.  The group of units modulo $mn$ is the same as the set of elements with $\gcd(x,mn) = 1$.  So that does it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $a \equiv 1 \mod(m)$ and $b \equiv 1\mod(n)$, then $ab \equiv 1\mod(mn)$